# Can't ping a host in the same network

Tags: linux, networking, lan, ping, bridge

So i'm setting a network of three PC's (PC1 - PC2 - PC3). PC2 eth0 is connected to PC1 eth0. And PC2 eth1 connected to PC3 eth0. I can ping PC2 with PC1 but i can't do the same for PC3. Also, are they consider on different networks, therefore i need to create a different subnet address for PC3 and PC2 eth1?

Comment: What type of cable are you using? For a network from a PC to another PC you need to use a cross over cable not a standard patch cable, is it possible one is cross over and one is not hence your problem?

Comment: I'm just doing a lab using gns3. So this topology is running in a virtual machine.

Comment: Oh ok slightly changes things...So can both PC1 and PC3 ping PC2 but PC1 and PC3 cannot ping each other? What subnet are they are all set too a Class C 255.255.255.0? Have you set a gateway on all three?

Comment: Will on of the PC's (either 1 or 3) can ping PC2. It depends who i configured first. For example, when i configured PC3 first and PC2. I was able to ping just fine. But when i added PC1, i couldn't. I set PC1 as 10.0.0.1/24, PC2 eth0 10.0.0.2/24, eth1 10.0.1.1/24. and PC3 as 10.0.1.4/24. I didn't set any gateway since i only want pc1 and 3 to be able to ping pc2 on their network.

Comment: Strange I cannot really see why this wouldn't work. What OS is PC2 running, Linux?

Comment: Yes both of them are running linux. I was aiming to set PC2 as a bridge between PC1 and PC3, but i wanted to make sure everything is connected properly.